# How to use patch mapping in kotlin spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

How do I use Patch mapping for updating a comment partially on its fields? At first I tried doing it this way but realized what if the user updates partially of it. What would be a way to update the comment  if user submits some of the fields

```
 @PatchMapping("/comment/{id}/")
    fun PatchCommentById(@PathVariable id: Long, @RequestBody comment: Comment): ResponseEntity<Comment> {
    
        val updatedComment = repo.save(Comment(
                id = id,
                body = comment.body,
                video_link = comment.video_link,
                image_link = comment.image_link,
        ))
        return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedComment)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simplest thing would be to always send all the data back and forth.

If that is not good enough you could use the ID to pull the existing comment from database and then null check on each property, such as:

```
    @PatchMapping("/comment/{id}/")
    fun PatchCommentById(@PathVariable id: Long, @RequestBody comment: Comment): ResponseEntity<Comment> {
    
        val original = repo.findById(id) // Not sure this is exactly the correct method

        val updatedComment = repo.save(original.copy( // Assuming your class is immutable
                body = comment.body ?: original.body,
                video_link = comment.video_link ?: original.video_link,
                image_link = comment.image_link ?: original.image_link
        ))
        return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedComment)
    }
```

This has the disadvantage that you have to make all field nullable. So a variation of the above would be to introduce a DTO (data transfer object) which has the same similar fields as your `Comment` class, but nullable. Thanks to Kotlin data classes this shouldn't be to big of a deal.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You would have to add the `@PatchMapping` annotation to the method. Something like this:

```kotlin
@PatchMapping("comment/by/id")
fun PatchCommentById(@PathVariable id: Long, @RequestBody comment: Comment): ResponseEntity<Comment>
```

Comment: Oh I already have that. I just forgot to include it

Comment: Ah, makes more sense. Ok, see my answer above.

Comment: How would I do DTO?

Comment: There is nothing special about it, it would just be another data class, but just tailored to what you need when sending the data between client and server.

Comment: You need to make sure that `Comment` is a data class.

Comment: so i would convert my entity from class Comment to data class Comment?

Comment: That's correct. If not possible, for one reason or another you could also call a new constructor instead of copy. But that's not as convenient.